# Doctrine наследование Single Table

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

Если использовать Single Table наследование в doctrine. И у 2 разных дочерних классов будут свойства с одинаковым именем к примеру (price), возникнут какие то трудности? Либо же лучше дать префиксы этим свойствам в таблице?

Comment: Прайс - это же число, ну и наследуйте свойство price от родителя. Если же вы собираетесь менять тип, то проблемы естественно будут, поскольку БД не может создать одно поле таблицы с разными типами. Если же у вас вообще разные наборы полей, то Single Table тут вообще не подходит

Comment: да, если бы все так просто. Не могу наследовать прайс, потому что в третьем дочернем классе его нет )

Comment: Тогда вы не сможете использовать Single Table